# add-ins for excel 2016 to faciliate review and reply

Tags: microsoft-excel

We work with excel spreadsheets to review works, and my superior make review notes with comments inserted in the subject cell, and i reply to the comment/modify the subject cell accordingly. 
I noted that comment box can not autofit itself to the content and it could drift away from its parent cell if you have made format adjustments. Is there a good tool/addins that I could work with?

Comment: Why don't you use the Review > Comment function?

Comment: @Leun4m that's what the OP is doing. The Review > Comment is just an Excel comment, and doesn't work like Word's comments.

Comment: @f19842 You could use [Kutools for Excel](https://www.extendoffice.com/product/kutools-for-excel/excel-comments-tool.html). It's a paid solution that extends Excel features, and apparently, gives you some extra features regarding comments.

Comment: Sry, I misunderstood that. However, [Excel Online](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-a-comment-7ced7849-f2d6-4fd4-9e02-65c2c05eee94) seems to work like the normal Word's comments